# Using SC.Get() from the JS library since the OAuth token in header update

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Since the SC Dev's **OAuth Tokens from URL to Header** update i can't get the SC.Get() function of the javascript SDK to work, as it appears to pass the OAuth token in the URL rather than a header resulting in a 401 error.

Is this to be expected or am I missing something? Is it possible to set the header through the properties?

I am using this version of the sdk: https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.3.2.js

here is the Get code I am using

```js
var route='/me/activities'      
var properties = {
  limit: 50
};
SC.get(route, properties, function(data) {})
```

Comment: I have just read here that they are no longer maintaining the JS API so I expect this is broken and will not be fixed by SC: https://github.com/soundcloud/api so the solution for now is to write my own get request function that can pass headers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using instead of SC.Get() now

```
function getStuff(route,callback){

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var data=JSON.parse(this.responseText)
            console.dir(data)
            callback(data)
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.soundcloud.com"+route+"?limit=200&linked_partitioning=true", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth "+getCookie("SCaccess"));
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Calling it like this

```
getStuff(route, function (data) {
    //do stuff with data
})
```